# Using array formula in Google Sheets and extract value for Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am developing a web app where the user need to sign in with username and password. So at first I used username : JJACKSON password : PASSWORD1 to log in to the web app and it worked fine but when I used a formula in my google sheet to combine the house number and street to create the username it is logging in. The page is just keep on loading after entering the username and password. The code is this

> =ArrayFormula(B2:B&"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2:C),"jalan","jln")," ",""))

I have attached some images to show how data is arranged in my google sheet. Hope anyone could help me with this thing. Thank you.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit?usp=sharing - Link to my google sheets

[image]

Comment: **P l e a s e** see  [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Aerials So sorry bro basically what I am asking here is that I have a formula ``=ArrayFormula(B2:B&"."&substitute(substitute(lower(C2:C),"jalan","jln")," ",""))`` to be updated in A2 but if I use any array formula in the sheet it is not working bro. Would you mind help me with it? I give you the link to my web app so that you would know what is the problem

Comment: @Aerials https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzQUn2snQPYuyVb_cwiabW7bHKcdnZFy4IXxSOmvUWQ2NCqHV4_3kTz9GAg8szfpwZn/exec - Link to my web app